# Zend Framework : How to handle "No route matched the request" error?

Tags: regex, exception, zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-route

In Bootstrap.php I have some custom routes using Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex.
Everything works fine except when user type in address bar a wrong link.

Ex :

`http://mysite/en/1-some-article.html` => This is a valid link that matches a ROUTE in Bootstrap.

But when user make a typo mistake like:

`http://mysite/en/1-some-article.**html'** or http://mysite/en/1-some-article.**hhtml**` , they are not match any ROUTE in Bootstrap, then Zend Framework throws an exception like : No route matched the request

Is there anyway to handle it, like redirecting to a custom page for "No matched routes"?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for advance!

Configuration (*from comment below*)

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"
;includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = ""
;resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ""
autoloaderNamespaces.Fxml = "Mycms_"
autoloaderNamespaces.Fxml = "Fxml_"
```

Comment: In your production environment, you would set `resources.frontController.params.throwExceptions` to false. This will cause the error to fall through to the `ErrorController`. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler.fourohfour and http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.exceptions.html

Comment: @Phil : I do have that line in my application.ini but nothing changed.

Comment: And you're running your app with prod settings?

Comment: @Phil : Yes,Im running the app with [production] settings.

Comment: Could you `var_dump()` the value of the `APPLICATION_ENV` constant, just to make sure?

Comment: @quangtruong1985 : did you override the default routing?

Comment: @Phil : Yep, this is what I get in Bootstrap.php with Zend_Debug::dump(APPLICATION_ENV) : string(10) "production"

Comment: Can you add the relevant sections of your config file (`application.ini`) to your question?

Comment: @prodigitalson : Yes, I did. I replaced it with this:
$defaultRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                        '',
                        array(
                            'module' => 'default',
                            'controller' => 'index',
                            'action' => 'index'
                        ),
                        array(
                        ),
                        'trang-chu.html'
        );
        $defaultRoute = $langRoute->chain($defaultRoute);

Comment: @quangtruong1985 Please don't post that stuff in comments. I've edited your question with the extra information.

Answer (score 0):

To make use of the `ErrorController`, you need to set the front controller `throwExceptions` attribute to `false`. Put this in your `[production]` configuration section

```
resources.frontController.params.throwExceptions = 0
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.exceptions.html and http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler.fourohfour.

I mentioned this in the comments above but you seem to have missed it (you have `displayExceptions` set to `false` but not `throwExceptions`).

Comment: Yeah, I put that line into my application.ini but nothing changed, too. The system keep throwing the exception.